# how to iterate in a file using keyword on a bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

in some file there is some content like:

```
scenario1{
 user_range:="1..100"
 ip_low:="192.168.1.1"
 ip_high:=192.168.1.100
 ...
}
scenario2{
user_range:="101..200"
ip_low:="192.168.2.1"
ip_high:=192.168.2.100"
...
}
...
```

I want replace some values using `sed -i`. But I can't figure out how to iterates by keyword "scenario" in order to change user_ranges and ips for the whole file.

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: changed fields of user_range, ip_low, ip_high.
I set manually some starting values (e.g. 250 for user range and some ips as well). `sed` changes `user range` in `scenario1` to 1..250, in `scenario2` 251..500 ...and so on. About ips: I should change only 3-rd octet of ip, increased by 1. It how my final result should looks like. But for me the main problem here is iterating inside a file by keywords.

Comment: Use `awk` or something else that you can write real logic, etc. in (`perl`, `python`, `ruby`, etc.).

Comment: please don't put complex explainations of your problem in comments. Update your Q so everyone can understand the desired output (actual evidence!) at the first reading. (And delete unneeded comments). Good luck!!!

Comment: Google this: associative arrays in bash

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS='\n}' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} 
        {from=250*c+1; to=250*(++c); 
         sub(/:=.*/,":=\""from".."to"\"",$2)} 
        {print $0 RT}' file

scenario1{
user_range:="1..250"
ip_low:="192.168.1.1"
ip_high:=192.168.1.100
...
}
scenario2{
user_range:="251..500"
ip_low:="192.168.2.1"
ip_high:=192.168.2.100"
...
}
```

ip addresses can be done similarly if there is a regular pattern.

Comment: this works only if there are 2 scenarios in the file. I was thinking about algorithm like: find `scenario` keyword and increase user_range on some values then find next `scenario` keyword,  increase all that stuff again based on values from previous scenario. but I am not sure can I reach it on bash.

Comment: Why do you think it is restricted to only two? That's for the input given. Did you try on a larger sample?

Comment: Only bash will be painful, use other powerful text tools at your disposal such as almighty awk.

Comment: oops, sorry. when I've added 3-rd scenario - i forgot to close a bracket :/ It actually works.
ok. I will try python for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using `sed` You may find it easier if you convert your file to a csv-format first.

```
tr '\n' ',' <testfile | tr '}' '\n' | tr -d "{" |sed 's/^,*//g;s/,*$//g' >csvfile
```

Since this results in one scenario per line, it will be much easier to use `sed`

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy with plain bash to seperate the values. I assume that the order of the key-value pairs and the number of newlines per stanza stay the same (just for demonstration purpose)

```
while read line
do
                        scenario=${line//\{/}
        read line;      user_range=${line}
        read line;      ip_low=${line}
        read line;      ip_high=${line}
        read line;      endchar=${line}

        # here you can insert every piece of code you need
        # to change your variables

        cat<<-EOF
                $scenario{
                $user_range
                $ip_low
                $ip_high
                }
        EOF
done <file_like_your_example >new_file
```